# Why we should use wiremock instead of Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, wiremock

I am having `Restclient` class which makes a rest call to URL whenever GET method is called on the `Restclient` object. I have a proper logic working behind.

Now Consider a case instead of using wiremock I used Mockito to mock the method GET on the `Restclient` object to return the appropriate response.

Does this have a disadvantage like the amount of code covered from the main module or both are equally good?

Comment: what programming language is this?

Comment: programming language is java...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Wiremock` provides a simulator for HTTP-based APIs while `Mockito` provides the mock implementation of the method/object.

> If we are using Mockito to mock HTTP-based method, it means we are
>   trying to return the object/response without testing any code to
>   invoke REST service, getting HTTP response and deserializing the same.

If we use the `Wiremock`, we will able to test close to reality as it will test invocation of REST call as well as deserialization of the response.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-difference-between-stub-mock-virtual-service-wojciech-bulaty/ is one good article to read, of course not by me :-)